Adding a virtual layer leads to slow perfomance and crashes in QGIS 3.36.1
I am creating a QGis project to help us track regular visits to specific properties in a small area. In order to do that I have the property cadastre layer which contains around 10000 individual polygons as well as an empty layer to register each visit.
I tried creating a virtual layer to generate a new polygon. The idea is, that it marks the property as visited and changes the color of the generated polygon depending on the days that have passed since the last visit.
#Virtual Layer 
SELECT k.*, f.*, 
       CASE
           WHEN k.day < 10 THEN 'green'
           WHEN k.day BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 'orange'
           WHEN k.day BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 'red'
           ELSE 'black'
       END AS color
FROM control AS k
JOIN propmap AS f ON ST_Within(k.geometry, f.geometry)

This results in QGIS being totally slowed down and unable to work. Sometimes it even crashes. Same problem happens on another machine.

Are the layers in a database? Is there a spatial index? The join in probably being computed for every records every time you touch the map. Consider using the virtual layer spatial index search_frame (research it a bit, the doc is too short). If you just need to display the result (vs working on the entire layer), you can try restricting the computation to visible points only as show here

Spatial indexes exist for both layers and both are in the same gpkg database. It computes it new for everytime I touch the map and disabling dynamic update makes it not be dynamic anymore. I follow your guides and update my comment accordingly.
